# Rolling sums across date range on data table by group in R

Tags: r, date, data.table, grouping, rolling-computation

I've got a data table with events and sub-events over time and I'm interested in creating two columns: (1) a cumulative rolling sum of whether an event occurred within 5 years from the date of the event and (2) a count of the number of sub-events (including the events) that took place within 5 years from the event date. Below is an example with code:

```
dt = data.table(id=c(rep(52749, 14), rep(46760, 15)),
                date=c("2007-01-30","2007-03-15","2007-11-27",
                       "2007-11-29","2008-10-09","2009-04-02",
                       "2011-01-06","2011-07-26","2012-01-25",
                       "2015-01-12","2016-09-13","2017-03-21",
                       "2017-08-29","2017-10-10","2008-01-01",
                       "2010-07-19","2011-01-14","2011-08-02",
                       "2011-08-02","2012-02-01","2012-02-01",
                       "2015-04-28","2015-10-19","2016-05-16",
                       "2016-12-22","2016-12-23","2017-05-16",
                       "2017-11-15","2018-02-22"),
                idx=c(seq_len(14), seq_len(15)),
                count=c(rep(14,14),rep(15,15)),
                event=c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                        1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

What this produces is the following:

```
id    date         idx  count    event  
52749 2007-01-30   1    14       1      
52749 2007-03-15   2    14       0      
52749 2007-11-27   3    14       1      
52749 2007-11-29   4    14       0      
52749 2008-10-09   5    14       1      
52749 2009-04-02   6    14       0      
52749 2011-01-06   7    14       1      
52749 2011-07-26   8    14       1      
52749 2012-01-25   9    14       0      
52749 2015-01-12  10    14       1      
52749 2016-09-13  11    14       1      
52749 2017-03-21  12    14       1      
52749 2017-08-29  13    14       0      
52749 2017-10-10  14    14       0  
46760 2008-01-01   1    15       1
46760 2010-07-19   2    15       1      
46760 2011-01-14   3    15       0      
46760 2011-08-02   4    15       1      
46760 2011-08-02   5    15       0      
46760 2012-02-01   6    15       1      
46760 2012-02-01   7    15       0      
46760 2015-04-28   8    15       1      
46760 2015-10-19   9    15       0      
46760 2016-05-16  10    15       1      
46760 2016-12-22  11    15       1      
46760 2016-12-23  12    15       0      
46760 2017-05-16  13    15       0      
46760 2017-11-15  14    15       1      
46760 2018-02-22  15    15       0
```

What I essentially need is the following:

```
id    date         idx  count    event  num_event_5yr_fu    num_subevents
52749 2007-01-30   1    14       1      4                   8
52749 2007-03-15   2    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2007-11-27   3    14       1      3                   6
52749 2007-11-29   4    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2008-10-09   5    14       1      2                   4
52749 2009-04-02   6    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2011-01-06   7    14       1      2                   3
52749 2011-07-26   8    14       1      1                   2
52749 2012-01-25   9    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2015-01-12  10    14       1      2                   4
52749 2016-09-13  11    14       1      1                   3
52749 2017-03-21  12    14       1      0                   2
52749 2017-08-29  13    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2017-10-10  14    14       0      NA                  NA
46760 2008-01-01   1    15       1      3                   6
46760 2010-07-19   2    15       1      3                   6
46760 2011-01-14   3    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2011-08-02   4    15       1      3                   6
46760 2011-08-02   5    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2012-02-01   6    15       1      3                   6
46760 2012-02-01   7    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2015-04-28   8    15       1      3                   7
46760 2015-10-19   9    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2016-05-16  10    15       1      2                   5
46760 2016-12-22  11    15       1      1                   4
46760 2016-12-23  12    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2017-05-16  13    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2017-11-15  14    15       1      0                   1
46760 2018-02-22  15    15       0      NA                  NA
```

Where the `num_event_5yr_fu` is counting the number of times an event occurred (or a cumulative sum along this) within 5 years from the event date (not including the event date), and the `num_subevents` is counting the number of records within 5 years from the event date (not including the event date).

I've been at this for quite some time and am stuck and would really appreciate some input on how this might be achieved. Thanks.

Comment: Please, can you clarify what the expected result is as the description of your requirements is not in line with the expected result shown? You say that both aggregates must not contain the event *date* but the expected result for `num_subevents` starts to count from the next *row* after the event although it has same event *date* (`id == 46760` and dates 2011-08-02 and 2012-02-01).

Comment: Yes this is correct, it should still contain the following record even if it has the same event date. It just cannot count the event date ON the current record, only records that come afterward. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

dt[, date := as.Date(date)][
  , num_event_5yr_fu := sapply(date,
                               function(x) sum(event[between(date, x + 1, x + years(5))])), by = id
  ][, num_subevents := sapply(date,
                              function(x) length(event[between(date, x + 1, x + years(5))])), by = id
  ][event == 0, `:=` (num_event_5yr_fu = NA, num_subevents = NA)]
```

Output:

```
       id       date idx count event num_event_5yr_fu num_subevents
 1: 52749 2007-01-30   1    14     1                4             8
 2: 52749 2007-03-15   2    14     0               NA            NA
 3: 52749 2007-11-27   3    14     1                3             6
 4: 52749 2007-11-29   4    14     0               NA            NA
 5: 52749 2008-10-09   5    14     1                2             4
 6: 52749 2009-04-02   6    14     0               NA            NA
 7: 52749 2011-01-06   7    14     1                2             3
 8: 52749 2011-07-26   8    14     1                1             2
 9: 52749 2012-01-25   9    14     0               NA            NA
10: 52749 2015-01-12  10    14     1                2             4
11: 52749 2016-09-13  11    14     1                1             3
12: 52749 2017-03-21  12    14     1                0             2
13: 52749 2017-08-29  13    14     0               NA            NA
14: 52749 2017-10-10  14    14     0               NA            NA
15: 46760 2008-01-01   1    15     1                3             6
16: 46760 2010-07-19   2    15     1                3             6
17: 46760 2011-01-14   3    15     0               NA            NA
18: 46760 2011-08-02   4    15     1                3             5
19: 46760 2011-08-02   5    15     0               NA            NA
20: 46760 2012-02-01   6    15     1                3             5
21: 46760 2012-02-01   7    15     0               NA            NA
22: 46760 2015-04-28   8    15     1                3             7
23: 46760 2015-10-19   9    15     0               NA            NA
24: 46760 2016-05-16  10    15     1                2             5
25: 46760 2016-12-22  11    15     1                1             4
26: 46760 2016-12-23  12    15     0               NA            NA
27: 46760 2017-05-16  13    15     0               NA            NA
28: 46760 2017-11-15  14    15     1                0             1
29: 46760 2018-02-22  15    15     0               NA            NA
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Many thanks @arg0naut, very helpful - in a clean and short format too.

Comment: How are 18-19th observations 5s for `num_subevents`?

Comment: Because the event date is not included - and there you have both event and sub-event date on the same day. OP seems to be OK with this approach, but can be modified to account for that.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a data.table approach using non-equi join:

```
library(lubridate) 

dt[, date := as.Date(date)]
dt[, end_date := date]
year(dt$end_date) <- year(dt$end_date) + 5
dt[, rowid := .I]

event_count = dt[dt, on = .(date < date , end_date >= date, id), 
                 allow.cartesian=TRUE][!is.na(rowid) & event == 1, 
                                       .(events = sum(i.event), num_subevents = .N), 
                                       by = .(rowid, id)]

dt[event_count, on = .(rowid, id), `:=`(num_event_5yr_fu = i.events,
                                        num_subevents = i.num_subevents)]

dt[, c("end_date", "rowid") := NULL]

dt

#        id       date idx count event num_event_5yr_fu num_subevents
#  1: 52749 2007-01-30   1    14     1                4             8
#  2: 52749 2007-03-15   2    14     0               NA            NA
#  3: 52749 2007-11-27   3    14     1                3             6
#  4: 52749 2007-11-29   4    14     0               NA            NA
#  5: 52749 2008-10-09   5    14     1                2             4
#  6: 52749 2009-04-02   6    14     0               NA            NA
#  7: 52749 2011-01-06   7    14     1                2             3
#  8: 52749 2011-07-26   8    14     1                1             2
#  9: 52749 2012-01-25   9    14     0               NA            NA
# 10: 52749 2015-01-12  10    14     1                2             4
# 11: 52749 2016-09-13  11    14     1                1             3
# 12: 52749 2017-03-21  12    14     1                0             2
# 13: 52749 2017-08-29  13    14     0               NA            NA
# 14: 52749 2017-10-10  14    14     0               NA            NA
# 15: 46760 2008-01-01   1    15     1                3             6
# 16: 46760 2010-07-19   2    15     1                3             6
# 17: 46760 2011-01-14   3    15     0               NA            NA
# 18: 46760 2011-08-02   4    15     1                3             5
# 19: 46760 2011-08-02   5    15     0               NA            NA
# 20: 46760 2012-02-01   6    15     1                3             5
# 21: 46760 2012-02-01   7    15     0               NA            NA
# 22: 46760 2015-04-28   8    15     1                3             7
# 23: 46760 2015-10-19   9    15     0               NA            NA
# 24: 46760 2016-05-16  10    15     1                2             5
# 25: 46760 2016-12-22  11    15     1                1             4
# 26: 46760 2016-12-23  12    15     0               NA            NA
# 27: 46760 2017-05-16  13    15     0               NA            NA
# 28: 46760 2017-11-15  14    15     1                0             1
# 29: 46760 2018-02-22  15    15     0               NA            NA
```

Comment: Really interesting approach - wonderful! I think @arg0naut's approach is a bit cleaner but this is great too. Thanks!

Comment: The cartesian product can be avoided by aggregating on the join parameters (`by = .EACHI`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a deviation between OP's specification and OP's expected result.

The OP has specified that *`num_event_5yr_fu` is counting the number of times an event occurred (or a cumulative sum along this) within 5 years from the event date (not including the event date), and the `num_subevents` is counting the number of records within 5 years from the event date (not including the event date).*

However, in OP's expected result `num_subevents` is counting the number of *records* within 5 years from the event date (not including the event ***row*** (= record?).

Therefore, two solutions are provided which cover both interpretations.

#### Reproducing OP's expected result

This approach reproduces OP's expected result (in contrast to the answers of [arg0naut](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903857/3817004) and [docendo discimus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54902265/3817004) which implement OP's requirements as described).

This approach *aggregates and updates in a non-equi join*. It includes the event date in the join but corrects the aggregates to count one event less.

```
library(data.table)
new_cols <- c("num_event_5yr_fu", "num_subevents")
result <- dt[
  , date := as.Date(date)][
    .(id = id, start = date, end = date + lubridate::years(5)), 
    on = .(id, date >= start, date <= end), 
    new_cols := .(sum(event) - 1, .N - 1L), by = .EACHI][
      event == 0, new_cols := NA][]
result
```

> ```
>        id       date idx count event num_event_5yr_fu num_subevents
>  1: 52749 2007-01-30   1    14     1                4             8
>  2: 52749 2007-03-15   2    14     0               NA            NA
>  3: 52749 2007-11-27   3    14     1                3             6
>  4: 52749 2007-11-29   4    14     0               NA            NA
>  5: 52749 2008-10-09   5    14     1                2             4
>  6: 52749 2009-04-02   6    14     0               NA            NA
>  7: 52749 2011-01-06   7    14     1                2             3
>  8: 52749 2011-07-26   8    14     1                1             2
>  9: 52749 2012-01-25   9    14     0               NA            NA
> 10: 52749 2015-01-12  10    14     1                2             4
> 11: 52749 2016-09-13  11    14     1                1             3
> 12: 52749 2017-03-21  12    14     1                0             2
> 13: 52749 2017-08-29  13    14     0               NA            NA
> 14: 52749 2017-10-10  14    14     0               NA            NA
> 15: 46760 2008-01-01   1    15     1                3             6
> 16: 46760 2010-07-19   2    15     1                3             6
> 17: 46760 2011-01-14   3    15     0               NA            NA
> 18: 46760 2011-08-02   4    15     1                3             6
> 19: 46760 2011-08-02   5    15     0               NA            NA
> 20: 46760 2012-02-01   6    15     1                3             6
> 21: 46760 2012-02-01   7    15     0               NA            NA
> 22: 46760 2015-04-28   8    15     1                3             7
> 23: 46760 2015-10-19   9    15     0               NA            NA
> 24: 46760 2016-05-16  10    15     1                2             5
> 25: 46760 2016-12-22  11    15     1                1             4
> 26: 46760 2016-12-23  12    15     0               NA            NA
> 27: 46760 2017-05-16  13    15     0               NA            NA
> 28: 46760 2017-11-15  14    15     1                0             1
> 29: 46760 2018-02-22  15    15     0               NA            NA
>        id       date idx count event num_event_5yr_fu num_subevents
> ```

Note that rows 18  to 20 (`id` == 46760 and `date` between 2011-08-02 and 2012-02-01) are in line with OP's expected result.

This can be verified by

```
all.equal(result, expected, check.attributes = FALSE)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

#### Reproducing the other answers

Here, only records are counted where the date is greater than the event date.

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- dt[, date := as.Date(date)][
  dt[event == 1, .(id, start = date, end = date + lubridate::years(5))],
  on = .(id, date > start, date <= end), 
  .(event = 1, sum(event), .N), by = .EACHI]
result <- dt[tmp, on = .(id, event, date), 
              c("num_event_5yr_fu", "num_subevents") := .(V2, N)][]
result
```

> ```
>        id       date idx count event num_event_5yr_fu num_subevents
>  1: 52749 2007-01-30   1    14     1                4             8
>  2: 52749 2007-03-15   2    14     0               NA            NA
>  3: 52749 2007-11-27   3    14     1                3             6
>  4: 52749 2007-11-29   4    14     0               NA            NA
>  5: 52749 2008-10-09   5    14     1                2             4
>  6: 52749 2009-04-02   6    14     0               NA            NA
>  7: 52749 2011-01-06   7    14     1                2             3
>  8: 52749 2011-07-26   8    14     1                1             2
>  9: 52749 2012-01-25   9    14     0               NA            NA
> 10: 52749 2015-01-12  10    14     1                2             4
> 11: 52749 2016-09-13  11    14     1                1             3
> 12: 52749 2017-03-21  12    14     1                0             2
> 13: 52749 2017-08-29  13    14     0               NA            NA
> 14: 52749 2017-10-10  14    14     0               NA            NA
> 15: 46760 2008-01-01   1    15     1                3             6
> 16: 46760 2010-07-19   2    15     1                3             6
> 17: 46760 2011-01-14   3    15     0               NA            NA
> 18: 46760 2011-08-02   4    15     1                3             5
> 19: 46760 2011-08-02   5    15     0               NA            NA
> 20: 46760 2012-02-01   6    15     1                3             5
> 21: 46760 2012-02-01   7    15     0               NA            NA
> 22: 46760 2015-04-28   8    15     1                3             7
> 23: 46760 2015-10-19   9    15     0               NA            NA
> 24: 46760 2016-05-16  10    15     1                2             5
> 25: 46760 2016-12-22  11    15     1                1             4
> 26: 46760 2016-12-23  12    15     0               NA            NA
> 27: 46760 2017-05-16  13    15     0               NA            NA
> 28: 46760 2017-11-15  14    15     1                0             1
> 29: 46760 2018-02-22  15    15     0               NA            NA
>        id       date idx count event num_event_5yr_fu num_subevents
> ```

The intermediate result is

```
tmp
```

> ```
>        id       date       date event V2 N
>  1: 52749 2007-01-30 2012-01-30     1  4 8
>  2: 52749 2007-11-27 2012-11-27     1  3 6
>  3: 52749 2008-10-09 2013-10-09     1  2 4
>  4: 52749 2011-01-06 2016-01-06     1  2 3
>  5: 52749 2011-07-26 2016-07-26     1  1 2
>  6: 52749 2015-01-12 2020-01-12     1  2 4
>  7: 52749 2016-09-13 2021-09-13     1  1 3
>  8: 52749 2017-03-21 2022-03-21     1  0 2
>  9: 46760 2008-01-01 2013-01-01     1  3 6
> 10: 46760 2010-07-19 2015-07-19     1  3 6
> 11: 46760 2011-08-02 2016-08-02     1  3 5
> 12: 46760 2012-02-01 2017-02-01     1  3 5
> 13: 46760 2015-04-28 2020-04-28     1  3 7
> 14: 46760 2016-05-16 2021-05-16     1  2 5
> 15: 46760 2016-12-22 2021-12-22     1  1 4
> 16: 46760 2017-11-15 2022-11-15     1  0 1
> ```

It does only contain results for `event == 1`. In the final *update join*, `event` is included in the keys to join on. For rows with  `event == 1` there is no match and thus the new columns are set to `NA` automatically.

#### Data

```
dt = data.table(id=c(rep(52749, 14), rep(46760, 15)),
                date=c("2007-01-30","2007-03-15","2007-11-27",
                       "2007-11-29","2008-10-09","2009-04-02",
                       "2011-01-06","2011-07-26","2012-01-25",
                       "2015-01-12","2016-09-13","2017-03-21",
                       "2017-08-29","2017-10-10","2008-01-01",
                       "2010-07-19","2011-01-14","2011-08-02",
                       "2011-08-02","2012-02-01","2012-02-01",
                       "2015-04-28","2015-10-19","2016-05-16",
                       "2016-12-22","2016-12-23","2017-05-16",
                       "2017-11-15","2018-02-22"),
                idx=c(seq_len(14), seq_len(15)),
                count=c(rep(14,14),rep(15,15)),
                event=c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
                        1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0))


expected <- 
fread("id    date         idx  count    event  num_event_5yr_fu    num_subevents
52749 2007-01-30   1    14       1      4                   8
52749 2007-03-15   2    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2007-11-27   3    14       1      3                   6
52749 2007-11-29   4    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2008-10-09   5    14       1      2                   4
52749 2009-04-02   6    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2011-01-06   7    14       1      2                   3
52749 2011-07-26   8    14       1      1                   2
52749 2012-01-25   9    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2015-01-12  10    14       1      2                   4
52749 2016-09-13  11    14       1      1                   3
52749 2017-03-21  12    14       1      0                   2
52749 2017-08-29  13    14       0      NA                  NA
52749 2017-10-10  14    14       0      NA                  NA
46760 2008-01-01   1    15       1      3                   6
46760 2010-07-19   2    15       1      3                   6
46760 2011-01-14   3    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2011-08-02   4    15       1      3                   6
46760 2011-08-02   5    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2012-02-01   6    15       1      3                   6
46760 2012-02-01   7    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2015-04-28   8    15       1      3                   7
46760 2015-10-19   9    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2016-05-16  10    15       1      2                   5
46760 2016-12-22  11    15       1      1                   4
46760 2016-12-23  12    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2017-05-16  13    15       0      NA                  NA
46760 2017-11-15  14    15       1      0                   1
46760 2018-02-22  15    15       0      NA                  NA")[
  , date := as.Date(date)]
```